# Achieving Controlled Parallelism In Chunked List

Tags: spring-boot, multithreading, kotlin, parallel-processing, kotlin-coroutines

I am fairly new to Kotlin and am writing a simple script to understand parallelism/multi-threading and concurrency in Kotlin. This is what I want to achieve.

Let's say I have a list of 10,000 users and I want to dump these users to my other service and I have an API for this in the other service. But, I can only send 50 users in single API call. But, the API can support about 2 TPS. Basically, 100 users per second.

This is what I have written so far

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking

import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.Semaphore

import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.withPermit

fun main() {
    val userList = getUsersFromDatabase()
    runBlocking {
        runMainJob(userList)
    }
    // Only execute this once runMainJob() has sent all the users.
    cleanup()
}

fun runMainJob(userList: List<Users>) {
    val semaphore = Semaphore(2)
    userList.chunked(50).forEach { group ->
        launch {
            semaphore.withPermit {
                callSecondService(group)
            }
        }
    }
}

fun cleanup() {
    // Should perform DB cleanup
}

fun getUsersFromDatabase(): Users {
    return Users()
}

fun callSecondService(group: List<Users>) {
    // Makes a network call
}

class Users(
    var id: Long,
    var name: String,
    var age: Long,
    var email: String,
)
```

The code runs fine but I cannot verify if the parallelism is working properly or is it running one by one.
I want to be able to control the parallelism because in future the other service might be able to take more simultaneous load.

How can I verify that my implementation is working as I need it to? Or am I doing something wrong here? or is there any other simpler way of achieving this?

Kotlin playground link if formatting isn't any good in this post https://pl.kotl.in/Ccr9ueZ7g

Comment: This code doesn't look runnable to me. Your calling `launch` with no CoroutineScope receiver, which isn't possible.

Answer (score -1):

The `withPermit` function will ensure that it will suspend the coroutine until a permit is released. read the `withPermit` and `acquire` documentation for more information.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.Semaphore
import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.withPermit

fun main() {
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob())
    val userList = scope.async { getUsersFromDatabase() }
    scope.launch {
        runMainJob(userList.await())
        cleanup()
    }

    Thread.sleep(100000)
}

suspend fun runMainJob(userList: List<User>) {
    var logNumber = 1
    val semaphore = Semaphore(2)
    userList.chunked(50).forEach { group ->
        semaphore.withPermit {
            println("log number: $logNumber")
            callSecondService(group)
            logNumber++
        }
    }
}

fun cleanup() {
    // Should perform DB cleanup
    delay(500)
    println("----------- Cleanup done -----------")
}

fun getUsersFromDatabase(): List<User> {
    return buildList {
        repeat(1000) {
            add(User())
        }
    }
}

suspend fun callSecondService(group: List<User>) {
    // Makes a network call
    delay(500)
    println(group)
}


class User(
    val id: Long = 1,
    val name: String = "",
    val age: Long = 2,
    val email: String = "",
)
```

`Thread.sleep(100000)` is necessary to keep the app alive